# How to Set Grid View Header Text As I Am Attaching list to Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am trying to add list in grid view but cant set its header text it is showing "item" in its text how to set its header text as my code is,

```
GridView1.DataSource = M5h;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I also tried it with template column but it is also not working then i remove add directly add list as datasource

it is showing like,

```
item

0.5
0.6
12
.36
0.46
0.8
0.9
11
2.1 
1.23
```

hopes for your suggestion thanks in advace

EDITED:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you Show me your `GridView1`'s code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="YourColumnDataField" HeaderText="item"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: i have "M5h" as list then should i write like <%#Eval("M5h")%> getting error "Error 5 Literal content ('<asp:BoundField  DataField="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'. G:\Musewerx Projects\Design Scoring\Design Scoring\InspectionEvaluation\NewCalc.aspx 29 
"

Comment: how to write in datafield as i have list to attach

Comment: tell me the column name of M5h !

Comment: List<double> M5h =new list<double> (); /// is simple like this how to know its column name ?

Answer (score 0):

you should define header tag.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
          <HeaderTemplate>
                 Item  //HeaderName
          </HeaderTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField  DataField="YourColumnDataField" HeaderText="item"/>
</Columns>
```